# Changing json format in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json output from a database quesry that looks as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": 1,
    "value": "27.18161362"
  },
  {
    "name": 2,
    "value": "323.69645128"
  },
  {
    "name": 3,
    "value": "23.16249181"
  }
]
```

I am trying to plug this into a script that will make charts from the data. The script requires the data to be in the following format:

```
{"script":
  [
    {"name":"1","value":27.18161362},
    {"name":"2","value":323.69645128},
    {"name":"3","value":23.16249181}
  ]
}
```

If it is not formatted in this way, the script claims that it is not valid json and contains no valud json head.

The output does use a valid json content header but that appears not to be enough for the script I am using.

So the question is, how can I convert the json output from a database call shown in first example, into the format the script is looking for show in the second example.

Code that creates json is fairly standard:

```
$stmt = $db3->prepare("SELECT week AS name, SUM(he.earnings) AS value FROM hotspot_earnings he INNER JOIN emrit_hotspots eh ON eh.hotspot_name = he.hotspot_name WHERE year = '2020' GROUP BY year, week");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($row, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Decode to array and rebuild array. Or make required format right when `fetch`ing data from db.

Comment: Thats kind of what I am asking, how would I make that kind of output that starts with `{"script": [ {` instead of `[ {` Unless I echo it myself line by line it always seems to start with `[` not `{`. So clearly something I am not understanding.

Comment: Show the code which builds the json.

Comment: @u_mulder Updated post, but its pretty standard just a basic SELECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt = $db3->prepare("SELECT week AS name, SUM(he.earnings) AS value FROM hotspot_earnings he INNER JOIN emrit_hotspots eh ON eh.hotspot_name = he.hotspot_name WHERE year = '2020' GROUP BY year, week");
$stmt->execute();
// Change here
$row = ['script' => $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)];
```

Comment: Good lord no wonder I am getting so many downvoites. Really that easy? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can edit the initial json output with php. If it's called by AJAX and you can control the php file you can try something like this. Just build the new array.

```
$new_array = array('script' => $row);
echo json_encode($new_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```